# Value as a type in interface

Tags: typescript

Why is this allowed in Typescript?

```
interface a {
  age: 42
}
```

42 is not a type. I thought interfaces should never have implementation details but "real" types like `age: number`. I see this as a shortcut to an enum `age: AgeEnum` but not a very pretty one.

Also it confuses the compiler if I do it (confuses 42 with a number). If I do:

```
class Person implements a { 
  public age: number = 42
}

error: Type number is not assignable to type 42
```

...which I think is kind of confusing!

I didn't find examples of this in the docs either. Not direct examples anyway.

Can anyone explain to my why this is allowed in Typescript?

Comment: In this case `42` is a numeric literal type

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface `a` states that `age` is limited to the value `42`. In your implementation you are redefining the type constraint of field `a` to `number`,  hence the error.

It is allowed in typescript because you can constrain to primitive literal values. This is actually a really good thing. What if you wanted to change age to `ageInDecades` and you assume that people would not live past `100` years in age. You could then define the interface constraint on `age` as follows:

```
interface IAge {
  ageInDecades: 0|10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80|90|100;
}
```

This is a rather weak example but I think you get the idea. You can do the same with allowed string values.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript allows for literal types for strings and numbers. In your case, `42` actually is a type: the number 42. This is different than type `number`.

Note that when you assign numbers and strings to class properties implementing an interface, TypeScript assumes that these are the primitive type rather than the literal type. This may either be a bug or a limitation of TypeScript. You can get around this by specifying the type during assignment.

```
interface a {
  age: 42;
  name: 'Andrew';
}

class Person implements a {
  age: 42 = 42;
  name: 'Andrew' = 'Andrew';
}
```

This is more useful when using union types like `42 | 43 | 44`.